# Displaying Special Characters Using Unicode

Tags: python, unicode

I want to know how to type a special character "Cherry" like the fruit. I got the Unicode string and attempted to display it, but for some reason it sees the `2` within `\u1F352` as part of the string and not the Unicode sequence, so it displays something completely different: `ἵ2`.

```
import sys
print('\u1F352')
```

Comment: Also note that the terminal program you are using might not support emoji - if that is the case, on WIndows download the "terminal" app from microsoft'Windows store, and  "iterm2" or kitti on Mac.  I think most terminal programs on Linux will just support emoji out of the box.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but you haven't asked a question, so it's difficult to post an answer, though Jason's found the solution. You might want to change the title to something like "Why does a 5-digit Unicode sequence turn into a 4-digit Unicode sequence followed by 1 digit?" For tips, see [ask].

Comment: \u escapes can only work with 16 bit characters, but [CHERRIES](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F352) is one of those "wide" ones (high codepoint) so you need a 32 bits escape \U.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the unicode escape:

```
>>> print("\U0001F352")
```

Using the unicode name:

```
>>> print("\N{cherries}")
```

Using the codepoint:

```
>>> print(chr(0x1f352))
```